# Cannot fetch shared google drive link (anyone) using apps script UrlFetchApp

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch

I am able to fetch and email the img2 but when I tried a shared-with-everyone image the below failsvand the email shows only empty box. What is gong on?
TIA.

```
    function sendEmail() {
//      var img2 = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/38/JPEG_example_JPG_RIP_001.jpg"
      var img = "https://drive.google.com/open?id=19JSe5jLnlllnUoYZlimeWAC39qLXwWs-"
        var subject = "Subject";
        var msgBody = "Body";    
        var imgFetch = UrlFetchApp
        .fetch(img2)
        .getBlob()
        .setName("imgFetch");

        msgBody = "<img src='cid:thisImg' style='width:100px; height:70px;' />";

        MailApp.sendEmail(mail, subject, "",
                          { htmlBody: msgBody + "<BR/><BR/>",
                           inlineImages:
                           {
                           thisImg: imgFetch,                   
                          }
                          }); 
    }
```

Comment: You have two variables for the image, and the one that you are using is commented out.  `.fetch(img2)`  img2 is commented out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification? In this modification, the endpoint was modified.

#### From:

```
var img = "https://drive.google.com/open?id=19JSe5jLnlllnUoYZlimeWAC39qLXwWs-"
```

#### To:

```
var img = "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=19JSe5jLnlllnUoYZlimeWAC39qLXwWs-"
```

Comment: Thanks! is this documented anywhere?

Comment: @rearThing Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. This URL can be retrieve by "webContentLink" of [Files: get of Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get). Even if the query of ``export=download`` is removed, the endpoint is works.