# Using IMPORTXML function on a shared XML file stored on Google Drive throws an error "Imported Content is Empty"

Tags: xml, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

This is my first go at using `importXML`. I have a `.xml` file stored on my Google Drive, called `CallsTrunc.xml`.

It can be viewed here:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eum_mv5sn7ve27ZF0L4zR7Pip_mPdgQw

The function I'm using to try to import it is:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eum_mv5sn7ve27ZF0L4zR7Pip_mPdgQw","//log")
```

And it returns an error:

> Imported content is empty.

I've also tried using `/alllogs` as the x-path, which also causes an error.

Using `/*` as the x-path throws this error:

> Result too large

and a huge mess of gibberish.

I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong if it's a fault with the link, the x-path, or the XML structure. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modified function:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1eum_mv5sn7ve27ZF0L4zR7Pip_mPdgQw", "//*[local-name()='log']/@*")
```

1. Modifying endpoint

   - From: `https://drive.google.com/open?id=1eum_mv5sn7ve27ZF0L4zR7Pip_mPdgQw`
   - To: `https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1eum_mv5sn7ve27ZF0L4zR7Pip_mPdgQw`
   - By this, the file can be read from the endpoint. [This recent thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55754450/7108653) might be useful.
2. Modifying xpath

   - From: `//log`
   - To: `//*[local-name()='log']/@*`
   - In this modification, all attributes are retrieved.

If this was not the result you want, I apologize.